# AssertJ - Is there a more fluent way to extract/map values?

Tags: java, assertj

I have following test code

```
ObjectNode jsonObject = ..
assertThat(jsonObject.get("level")).isNotNull();
assertThat(jsonObject.get("level").get("object")).isNotNull();
assertThat(jsonObject.get("level").get("object").textValue()).isEqualTo("my value");
```

I would like to write this in a more fluent way such as

```
assertThat(jsonObject.get("level")).isNotNull()
    .extracting(jsonNode -> jsonNode.get("object"))
    .isNotNull()
    .extracting(JsonNode::asText)
    .isEqualTo("my value");
```

It does not seem that `extracting()` was designed for this.
Is there any other more fluent way to write out initial test code?

Answer (score 1):

I would give a serious try to https://github.com/lukas-krecan/JsonUnit, it is designed to be json friendly.